# Is there anything like multiblock readings in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, database

I found some interesting explanations about multi-block readings in Oracle. I found it a very useful feature, so I tried to find something similar in SQL Server without success.

Is there anything similar to multi-block readings in SQL Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An 8K page (block) is the smallest unit for SQL Server data IO. SQL Server optimizes scans by reading pages in multiples of 8 contiguous pages (64K) extents. Also, [read-ahead reads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms191475(v=sql.105)) are done using scatter-gather IO of up to 4MB at once in newer SQL Server versions so that data are prefetched and ready in the buffer cache when needed by the execution plan operators.